# Python 2 Stack and LinkedList implementation

Tags: python, linked-list, stack

I'm currently implementing data structures and algorithms I studed in my college course. This is my implementation of a singly linked list and a stack. I would appreciate some feedback in terms of the code quality.

My LinkedList:

```
from random import randint

class Node:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.current = x
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.head = Node(x)

    def insert(self, x):
        new_entry = Node(x)
        new_entry.next = self.head
        self.head = new_entry

    def search(self, x):
        node = self.head

        while node.current is not x:
            if node.next is None:
                break
            node = node.next

        if node.current is x:
            return x
        else:
            return None

    def contains(self, x):
        retrieved = self.search(x)
        return retrieved is x

    def delete(self, x):
        try:
            node = self.head

            while node.next.current is not x:
                node = node.next

            if node.next.current is x:
                node.next = node.next.next
        except AttributeError:
            print str(x) + " is not in the linked list"

    def traverse(self):
        node = self.head
        text = ""  # type: str

        while node is not None:
            text += str(node.current) + "->"
            node = node.next

        return text
```

My stack:

```
class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def push(self, e):
        self.data.append(e)

    def pop(self):
        return self.data.pop()

    def prnt(self):
        print self.data

def is_integer(val):
    try:
        int(val)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def is_binary_operator(val):
    return val is '+' or val is '-' or val is '*' or val is '/'

def postfixEval(stack, expression):
    symbols = expression.split()

    for symbol in symbols:

        if is_integer(symbol):
            s = int(symbol)
            stack.push(s)
        elif is_binary_operator(symbol):
            s2 = stack.pop()
            s1 = stack.pop()

            if symbol is '+':
                a = s1 + s2
            elif symbol is '-':
                a = s1 - s2
            elif symbol is '*':
                a = s1 * s2
            elif symbol is '/':
                a = s1 / s2

            stack.push(a)

    return stack.pop()
```

Comment: This should be 2 separate questions, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notes on `LinkedList`:

- The import is unused.
- It should allow creation of an empty list.
- Normally a linked list inserts items [after the last item](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly_linked_list). Maybe I'm confused by the way `insert` works, but it looks like in your case `head` is always the *last inserted* entry in the list, and the list is traversed from `head` **backwards** through history using `.next`.
- `delete` should use `search`.

Notes on `Stack`:

- `self.data` should be `self.entries` or something else descriptive.
- `prnt` should be `as_string` or even `__str__`.
- `int(val)` does **not** check whether something is an integer, it just tries to *convert* a value to an integer.
- `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` are *arithmetic*, not binary, operators.
- In Python 3 [mathematical operators are modeled as functions](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/operator.html).
- `is_integer`, `is_binary_operator` and `postfixEval` should not be part of `Stack` - they are not fundamental to the stack in any way.

Comment: '`int(val)` does not ...' No, but it does raise a `ValueError` if the argument can't be converted to an integer (which, when caught, results in the function returning `False`).

Answer (score 2):

```
def is_integer(val):
    try:
        int(val)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Should be written:

```
def is_integer(val):
    try:
        int(val)            
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True
```

This is cleaner because what may trigger the exception is not the return statement but when `int()` tries to convert `val`. Besides, maybe what you really are looking for is:

```
import numbers
def is_integer(val):
    return isinstance(val, numbers.Integral)
```

This way, you do not have to worry about exceptions since they are managed under the hood and, I think that is also the data type you want to deal with.

def prnt(self):
       print self.data

A stack has `push()`, `pop()` and `size()` operations, but nothing like `prnt()`. If you need the functionality prnt() is doing, take advantage of the Python `__repr__()` magic method instead:

```
 def __repr__(self):
     return '{} '.format(self.data)
```